# How to check if Iterator.next() is == null?

Tags: java, null, iterator, anonymous-class

How do I check if the next element in the list is null ?

```
while(it.hasNext()){

            System.out.println(it.next()+"\n");
        }
```

this is how I tried, but when the last element is null it prints it as null.

I tried to change it

```
 while(it.hasNext()){
    if(it.next()==null){
    }else             
        System.out.println(it.next()+"\n");
            }
```

but this just makes it worst because some of the elements don't even print!

This is my Iteration method/anonymous class

```
public Iterator<Filmi> iterator3DFilms ()throws FilmiException{
        if(filmList.isEmpty())
            throw new FilmiException("No Films on the list");
        return new Iterator<Filmi>(){
            private int index=0;
            public boolean hasNext(){
                return index <filmList.size();
            }
            public Filmi next(){
                Filmi lb = filmList.get(index++);

                if(lb.is3D()== true)
                    return lb;
                if(hasNext())
                    return next();
                return null;
            }
            public void remove(){}
        };
    }
```

The null print only happens at the last element 
Thank you.

Comment: Why there are null values there in the first place? I think the main problem is in the code that populate the iterator. Can't you control that ?

Comment: Does the iterator give you the first film in the list?

Comment: in the Filmi next() method it test if the film is 3d and hasNext() if it dosent have any of those it returns a null .thats when the null comes from, but i have to return something .

Comment: @keiwan yes it does

Comment: Every time you call `it.next()` you get the next value.  If you want to use this value more than once you have to use a variable and look at this variable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Naturally, code like

```
if (it.next() == null){
} else {
    System.out.println(it.next()+"\n");
}
```

will consume every other non-`null` element, as you are observing. Plus calling `it.next()` without checking `it.hasNext()` is a recipe for disaster.

Why not write

```
Foo/*ToDo - use the correct type here*/ foo = it.next()
if (foo != null){
    /*ToDo*/
}
```

instead?

Answer (score 8):

No it cannot work this way because if `it.next()` is not `null` you call `it.next()` twice which will make you skip a value that could not even be available.

Use a variable instead as next:

```
Object o = it.next();
if (o != null) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

you should use stream instead of iterator.

```
filmList.stream().filter(film->film!=null).filter(film->film.is3D())
```

Edit:
or, if you'r not in Java 8 :

```
Predicate<Film> isNotNullAnd3D = new Predicate<Person>() {
        public boolean apply(Film f) {
            return f != null && f.is3D();
        }
    };

Collection2.filter(filmList, isNotNullAnd3D)
```

Comment: That's only a solution if OP is using Java 8, isn't it?

Comment: Not sure that's necessary a bad thing; Java 8 solutions ought to be considered acceptable on the Java tag. Have an upvote!

Comment: I am not arguing that. Just found it worth mentioning because especially beginners may not be aware of that this functionality is Java 8+ only.

Comment: yes, but if you don't use Java 8, you can use similar stuff with the lib guava and the class Collections2, method filter

Comment: But where do you draw the line? Generics are Java 5 onwards, for example.

Comment: @Bathsheba: 
I understand that if you still are on Java 7, you can forgot to write-it on your post. But if you'r java 4, he will have precise it on his post, I hope.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning [Objects::nonNull](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#nonNull-java.lang.Object-) could be used instead of `film->film!=null`

Answer (score 1):

You never mentioned why you use iterators explicitly in the first place.
Why not use implicit iterator notation like this ? :

```
for (Film film : filmList) {
  if (film != null ){
     ....
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to what others said: in case you are doing a for-each loop with a **primitive type** like `int`

```
for (int node : input) {
    doSomething(node);
}
```

you might want to consider using the **Wrapper** class instead:

```
for (Integer node : input) {
    if (node == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    doSomething(node);
}
```